# Access other injected methods from injected plugin in Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I feel like this is a really stupid question  and I'm missing something really obvious but I'll ask anyway.

I have a Nuxt plugin that injects a function into the Vue instance, but I need to access another injected method (which is injected by a module, buefy) from within my method. Here's the plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$disp_error = (err) => {
  console.error(err)
  Vue.$snackbar.open({
    duration: 60000,
    message: 'Uh oh! Something went wrong. If it keeps happening, please contact us with this error: ' + err.toString(),
    type: 'is-danger'
  })
}
```

However it says `$snackbar` is undefined. I guess I could solve it by using `this` as a second argument when I call `this.$disp_error` within my components, and then using the `this` context to call `$snackbar` in my method, but I don't really want to use add second argument.

Could someone remind me what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: dont think it will solve your problem, but better to use nuxt inject. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject